# What is the difference between sugar cane and cane sugar?

Tags: confusables

I've heard people use them interchangeably.
Just so I don't go crazy, what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cane sugar comes from sugarcane. Sugarcane is the crop, cane sugar is the refined grains of sugar.

Edit: you also get other things from sugarcane, such as falernum, molasses, rum, cachaça, bagasse and ethanol.

There are photos of the crop are on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarcane).

Comment: ‘Sugarcane’ as one word seems like an Americanism to me; in the UK it's ‘sugar cane’, two words.

Answer (score 12):

When you have two nouns together, usually the second is the basic meaning, and the first one acts like an adjective to modify it.  An *apple tree* is a kind of tree.  A *tree house* is a kind of house.

So ***sugar cane* is a kind of cane**.  (It’s a cane from which sugar is produced.)  ***Cane sugar* is a kind of sugar**.  (It’s sugar that’s produced from cane.)

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote, by the way?  I’m not offended by getting them, but it would be helpful to know why.

Comment: You're offended, obviously.

Comment: +1 The answer looks obvious because the question is simple.  For a native speaker that is.

Comment: Downvoting an answer should always be accompanied by an explanatory comment, I feel. If we have to ask for an explanation, what does that really say about communication in this community? How else will the author of the downvoted answer hAve a chance to learn about what aspect of the answer was perceived as not suitable/wrong/not welcome.

Comment: +1 for not just answering, but giving the general principle that explains why it's so.

Answer (score 5):

Cane **sugar** is a type of **sugar**, sugar **cane** is a type of **cane**. The difference is which is the noun and which is the adjective.

Cane sugar is a type of sugar derived from a particular cane plant.

Sugar cane is a type of cane plant that can be used to make sugar.

For our next question we want to know, which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Comment: snap!  Almost identical answers, almost identical timing :-)